# How does $e^{i\ln(2)}=2^i$

Tags: complex-numbers

How does $e^{i\ln(2)}=2^i$?

I apologise in advance for the simplicity of the question, but I just can't seem to realise why... My mind has gone blank!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $e^{i\ln(2)} = \left ( e^{\ln(2)} \right)^i = 2^i$

Comment: Of course! Thank you, @BalarkaSen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write that as
$$ e^{i\ln(2)} = (e^{ln(2)})^i = 2^i $$
Because $e^{ln(x)}=x$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the three following properties

$$a\ln b=\ln (b^a)$$
$$e^{a\ln b}=e^{\ln (b^a)}$$
$$e^{\ln a}=a$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula $a^x=e^{x\cdot ln(a)}$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of complex exponents is :

$$e^{bi} = \cos(b) + i \sin(b)$$

Assuming that the definition is consistent, we wish to know what

$$\left(e^{bi}\right)^c= ?$$

So applying the definition:
$$\left(e^{bi}\right)^c= \left(\cos(b) + i \sin(b)\right)^c$$

Applying trig identies and other stuffs...

$$ = \cos(bc) + i \sin(bc)$$
$$ = e^{bci}$$

The main point I'm trying to get across is that you can't just assume $\left(e^{bi}\right)^c = e^{bci}$ just because we are using an exponential notation, it follows from definition.  The definition could have been made where this doesn't follow, or there might not have even existed a definition where relations like this follow.  So don't let the other answers mislead you into thinking that you can just arbitrarily apply rules from one domain (reals) to another (complex).

Anyway, combine that with $2 = e^{\ln(2)}$ as the other answers mentioned and you get your relation.